# Condition use where in sql for android development error

Tags: android, sql-server

I was creating  update to sql server in android development

this is my code

```
String query = "UPDATE dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS SET
    LAST_UPDATED_USERNAME = '" + Username  + "'
    , ENROLLMENT_SCHEDULE = convert(datetime,'" + Enrolfix + "')
    , STATUS_ID = '" + Status  + "'
    , LAST_UPDATED ='" + formattedDate
    + "'where REGISTRATION_NUMBER  =  '" + RegisBaru  + "'   "
```

My error is:

> converting data type varchar to numeric

For additional info variable `REGISTRATION_NUMBER`   is numeric.

Comment: Don't you have the ability to use SQL Parameters in Android development? This sort of dynamic SQL is not only dangerous but gives you errors as you are finding.

Comment: you need to convert `RegisBaru` to string before concatenate. Infact any value that is not string should be converted first

Comment: ok its solved thank you @S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so sure but you can try this:

Remove `'`

```
+ "'where REGISTRATION_NUMBER  =  " + Integer.parseInt(RegisBaru)  + "   "
```

Comment: This is a conflict if this `RegisBaru`if it is a string. maybe you have to change the datatype of your  `REGISTRATION_NUMBER` to `varchar`

Comment: REGISTRATION_NUMBER  is numeric type

Comment: I got you, but the what is the value of this `RegisBaru`? A String or Number?

Comment: RegisBaru a String, i want input to numeric type

Comment: Do you have an example value of this `RegisBaru`?

Comment: RegisStr=txtregis.getText().toString(); String RegisBaru =  RegisStr;

Comment: That value triggered your error because your `REGISTRATION_NUMBER` is numeric type. Try to change it to varchar.

Comment: sorry Registration_number it must numeric type and i was tring in php no problem but i'm try in android its failed